# If $H, K, L$ are subgroups of a group $G$ and $LH = HL$ and $LK = KL$, is it true that $L(H \cap K) = (H \cap K) L$?

Tags: group-theory

Title says it all: if $H, K, L$ are subgroups of a group $G$ and $LH = HL$ and $LK = KL$, is it true that $L(H \cap K) = (H \cap K) L$?

This seems similar in flavor to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133843/let-g-be-a-group-and-h-k-l-be-subgroups-with-h-subseteq-k-prove-that-k), but without any constraints on containment.  I'd thought one might be able to use the fact that $LHK = HKL$ together with some form of second-isomorphism-theorem argument, but wasn't able to make it stick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the [$QR$ decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) of $G=GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.
Every element of $G$ can be written (uniquely) as a product
$$g = q \cdot r$$
where $q$ is orthogonal and $r$ is upper triangular with all positive diagonal elements, so we have the decomposition
$$G = Q \cdot R$$

Taking inverses we get $QR = RQ = G$.

Taking transposes we also get $QL= LQ=G$, where $L$ consists of lower triangular matrices with positive diagonal entries. Now $R\cap L=D$ consists of diagonal matrices with positive entries. Note that the set $DK$ consist of matrices with orthogonal rows, while $KD$ consists of matrices with orthogonal columns, so they are different.

$\bf{Added:}$ We can get a similar counterexample with finite groups. For instance, consider $G = GL(2, \mathbb{F}_p)$, where $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the field with $p$ elements, and $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. The condition on $p$ is such that the equation $a^2 + b^2 = 0$ has only trivial solution in $\mathbb{F}_p$. We now have a similar decomposition
$$G = Q R= RQ = QL=LQ$$
where $Q$ consists of matrices $\left( \begin{matrix} a & - b \\b & a \end{matrix}\right)$, $R$ consists of upper triangular matrices, and $L$ of lower triangular matrices. It is easy to see that $Q(L\cap R) \ne (L\cap R) Q$.

Note: This Gram-Schmidt procedure only works in dimension $2$, since a quadratic form in $n>2$ variables over a finite field has an [isotropic vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_vector), cf [Chevalley-Waring theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem).

Comment: This is a really beautiful example.

I think the second sentence should read "where $q$ is orthogonal"?

I wasn't aware of the alternate $QR$ decomposition for finite fields -- maybe this is common knowledge in algebra, and maybe it's obvious; do you happen to know of a reference?

Comment: @Greg: Thank you! it's a nice question!  Now, about the $QR$ decomposition, it makes the columns of a $2\times 2$ matrix orthogonal ( replace $c_2 \mapsto c_2 - \frac{\langle c_2, c_1\rangle} {\langle c_1, c_1 \rangle} \cdot c_1$, then rescales them to get them in $Q$. Now we do not have uniqueness,, but it's OK.

Comment: Ah - just like computing real/complex $QR$ via Gram–Schmidt.  Lovely!  Thank you again!

Answer (score 6):

No. Try $G=A_5$, $L = \langle (1,2,3,4,5) \rangle$, $H=G_1 = \langle (2,3)(4,5),(3,4,5)\rangle$, $K=G_2 = \langle(1,3)(4,5),(3,4,5)\rangle$, so $H \cap K = G_{12}=\langle(3,4,5)\rangle$.

So, $|L|=5$, $|H|=|K|=12$, and $HL=LH=KL=LK=G$.

But you can check that $L(H \cap K)$ and $(H \cap K)L$ are distinct subsets of order $15$.

Comment: Does $G_p$ denote the subgroup that fixes $p$?  So $G_1$ is the set of even permutations that fix $1$, and $G_{12}$ is the set of even permutations that fix both $1$ and $2$?  Maybe this is easy to deduce from the generators, I wasn't quite sure.

Comment: Yes, $G_1$ is the stabilizer of the point $1$ and it is isomorphic to $A_4$ (or order $12$). And $G_{i2}$ is the stabilizer of both $1$ and $2$, and is isomorphic to $A_3$ of order $3$.